# On how to write the Lagrangian

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have a very simple question regarding the Lagrange multiplier. Everything can be seen in the most basic setting of two functions $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Thus, given the maximization problem

\begin{align}
\max_{x, y}\ & F (x, y) \\
\text{sub}\ \ & g(x, y) = m ,
\end{align}

I always found the corresponding Lagrangian written as

\begin{equation*}
L (x, y , \mu) = F (x, y) + \mu [m - g(x,y)]
\end{equation*}

or

\begin{equation*}
L (x, y , \mu) = F (x, y) - \mu [g(x,y) - m].
\end{equation*}

> Thus, the question is if it possible to write the Lagrangian as
>
> \begin{equation*} L (x, y , \mu) = F (x, y) + \mu [g(x,y) - m],
>  \end{equation*}
>
> the point being that when we take $L_\mu = 0$, we still have nothing
> more than the original constraint.

Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your way of writing the Lagrangian is also valid. The Lagrangian multiplier term can be either added or subtracted, it doesn't matter. You can also use a fourth way of writing the Lagrangian:

$$L(x,y,\mu)=F(x,y)-\mu[m-g(x,y)]$$

All that matters is that the term multiplied by $\mu$ gives $m=g(x,y)$ when equated to zero.